# Placing 3 div's side by side (1 fixed, 2 with 100% of free space and 3 auto)

Tags: html, css

I have a layout where I have 3 columns.

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="logo"></div>
    <div id="search-input"></div>
    <div id="user-name"></div>
</div>
```

How can I place these 3 blocks in one line without JS, calc and flexbox if I need:

- `logo` should be fixed
- `user-name` should have auto width
- `search-input` should places on the left free space between `logo` and `user-name` blocks. It has to be fluid container.

Comment: what's the order? (right to left)

Comment: the logo block in the left and the user-name block in the right. The search block between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this is what you want. you can add content of user-name to see how it work.

```css
.wraper{
   width: 100%;
   border: 1px solid red;
}
#logo{
  float:left;
  width:250px;
  height: 50px;
  border:1px solid #CCC;
  display:block;
  background-color:yellow;
}
#search-input{
  margin-left:260px;
  min-height:50px;
  display:block;
  background-color:red;
}
#user-name{
  float:right;
  display:block;
  height:50px;
  background-color:#FFF;
}
#search-input > .inner{
  height:50px;
  background-color:red;
  margin-right:20px;
}
#user-name > .inner{
  background-color:green;
  min-width:150px;
  height:50px;
  margin-left:10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="logo">Logo</div>
    <div id="user-name">
      <div class="inner">
        user name
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="search-input">
      <div class="inner">
        search input
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use flexbox:

```css
#wrapper {
   display: flex;
/* flex-direction: row; <-- by default */
}
#logo {
  flex: 0 0 200px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
#user-name {
  flex: none;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
#search-input {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="logo">logo</div>
  <div id="search-input">input</div>
  <div id="user-name">user name</div>
</div>
```

Comment: flexbox is not preferable way. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @AlexanderShlenchack - why not? and why not mention this in your question if you're aware of this limitation of yours? people (me...) are taking from their spare time to help you, don't you think it's kind to inform them (me...) not to was their (my) time?

Comment: Sorry for wasting your time. I've upped your answer but for me it's a not answer.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<div id="wrapper">
        <div id="logo"></div>
        <div id="search-input"></div>
        <div id="user-name"></div>
    </div>
<style>
#logo{float:left;padding:2px}
#search-input{width:50%;float:left;padding:2px}
#user-name{width:auto;float:left;padding:2px}  
</style>
```

Comment: search-input should places on the left free space between logo and user-name blocks. It has to be a fluid block

Answer (score 0):

```
#wrapper{
   display:block;
}
#logo{
   display:inline-block;
   width:30%;
   float:left;
}
#search-input{
  width:50%;
  display:inline-block;
  float:left;
}
#user-name{
  width:auto;
  display:inline-block;
  float:left;
}
```

This will keep them in one line.